# How to apend a linkedlist onto a specific node of a linkedlist?

Tags: java, linked-list, append

I want to know how to add a linkedlist to a specific index of another linkedlist. Picture of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

I want to add `item` to "John". `item2` to "Amy" and etc

My code so far:

```
import java.util.*;
public class LinkedListTest {
     public static void main(String args[]) {

         LinkedList<String> person = new LinkedList<String>();
         LinkedList<String> item = new LinkedList<String>();
         LinkedList<String> item2 = new LinkedList<String>();

         person.add("John");
         person.add("Amy");
         person.add("Bob");
         person.add("Michael");


         item.add("Eggs");
         item.add("Bread");
         item.add("Ham");

         item2.add("Toilet roll");
         item2.add("Eggs");


         for(int i = 0; i < item.size(); i++){
         person.addFirst(item.get(i));
         }
         System.out.println(person);

     }
}
```

Comment: The good and object-oriented solution: Don’t put strings (person names) into your first linked list. Instead create a class `Customer` with fields `personName` and `itemsBought`. The latter will itself be a reference to the linked list of items. Now make a list of `Customer` objects for the persons. Then it will be straightforward and natural to add the linked list of items to each customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good and object-oriented solution is: Don’t put strings (person names) into your first linked list. Instead create a class `Customer` with fields `personName` and `itemsBought`. The latter will itself be a reference to the linked list of items. Now make a list of `Customer` objects for the persons. Then it will be straightforward and natural to add the linked list of items to each customer.

```
public class Customer {

    String personName;
    List<String> itemsBought;

    public Customer(String personName) {
        this.personName = personName;
        itemsBought = Collections.emptyList();
    }

    public void setItemsBought(List<String> itemsBought) {
        this.itemsBought = itemsBought;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return personName + " bought " + itemsBought;
    }

}
```

With this class you can do:

```
    LinkedList<Customer> person = new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<String> item = new LinkedList<String>();
    LinkedList<String> item2 = new LinkedList<String>();

    person.add(new Customer("John"));
    person.add(new Customer("Amy"));
    person.add(new Customer("Bob"));
    person.add(new Customer("Michael"));


    item.add("Eggs");
    item.add("Bread");
    item.add("Ham");

    item2.add("Toilet roll");
    item2.add("Eggs");

    person.get(0).setItemsBought(item);
    person.get(1).setItemsBought(item2);

    System.out.println(person);
```

This prints:

```
[John bought [Eggs, Bread, Ham], Amy bought [Toilet roll, Eggs], Bob bought [], Michael bought []]
```

I would find it more convenient to build the list bottom-up: add the items to the customer before adding the customer to the person list. We can add further convenience with a varargs constructor that accepts both name and items. Think if we could do:

```
    person.add(new Customer("John", "Eggs", "Bread", "Ham"));
    person.add(new Customer("Amy", "Toilet roll", "Eggs"));
    person.add(new Customer("Bob"));
    // etc.
```

If we change the `Customer` constructor to the following, we can:

```
public Customer(String personName, String... itemsBought) {
    this.personName = personName;
    this.itemsBought = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(itemsBought));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a Map to achieve this. Each key of the map represents the "Customer" and the `LinkedList` can be used to store the "items" for each customer.

```
public class LinkedListTest {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
         Map<String, LinkedList<String>> personItems = new LinkedHashMap<>();

         LinkedList<String> item = new LinkedList<String>();
         LinkedList<String> item2 = new LinkedList<String>();

         item.add("Eggs");
         item.add("Bread");
         item.add("Ham");

         item2.add("Toilet roll");
         item2.add("Eggs");

         personItems.put("John", item);
         personItems.put("Amy", item2);    


         for(String cust: personItems.keySet()){
             System.out.println(personItems.get(cust));
         }

     }
}
```

A couple of advantages of this is:

1. You can look up the items list for a customer based on the name.
2. Plus, by using a `LinkedHashMap`, the order in which you insert customers is retained.

---

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You want to **associate a person with a list of items**, so make **pairs**, Map are made for the same, you can initialize the List before adding the pair into the Map, I've also added code to print the stuff (see comments into code) :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String,LinkedList<String>> person = new HashMap<String,LinkedList<String>>();
        LinkedList<String> item = new LinkedList<String>();
        LinkedList<String> item2 = new LinkedList<String>();

        //Add your people into the Map
        person.put("John",item);
        person.put("Amy",item2);
        person.put("Bob",new LinkedList<String>());
        person.put("Michael",new LinkedList<String>());

        //Add stuff to item for John
        item.add("Eggs");
        item.add("Bread");
        item.add("Ham");

        //Add stuff to item for Amy
        item2.add("Toilet roll");
        item2.add("Eggs");

        //To add stuff for Bob :
        person.get("Bob").add("Chocolate");

        //To add stuff for Michael :
        person.get("Michael").add("Chips");

        //To see what's inside for ONE person :
        for(String stuff : person.get("John")){
            System.out.println(stuff);
        }

        //To see ALL :
        for(String people : person.keySet()){
            System.out.println(people+" has bought :");
            for(String stuff : person.get(people)){
                System.out.println(stuff);
            }
        }
    }
```

And in fact I'm not sure LinkedList is necessary, a simple ArrayList maybe be sufficient, look at this too : http://www.sergiy.ca/img/doc/java-map-collection-cheat-sheet.gif

Answer (score 1):

You are defining person as a LinkedList of Strings.

So obviously, one cannot add a LinkedList to a String.

You could have a linked list of linked lists of Strings:

```java
LinkedList<LinkedList<String>> person = new LinkedList<>();
LinkedList<String> item   = new LinkedList<String>();
LinkedList<String> item2  = new LinkedList<String>();

person.add(new LinkedList<>(Collections.singleton("John")));
person.add(new LinkedList<>(Collections.singleton("Amy")));
person.add(new LinkedList<>(Collections.singleton("Bob")));
person.add(new LinkedList<>(Collections.singleton("Michael")));

item.add("Eggs");
item.add("Bread");
item.add("Ham");

item2.add("Toilet roll");
item2.add("Eggs");

person.get(0).addAll(item);
person.get(1).addAll(item2);

System.out.println(person);
```

But then you'd end up:

- mixing the concept of a person with the concept of items.
- having to deal with indices when accessing a particular person.

Best choice for future headaches.

Preferred choice would be to go `Map<String, LinkedList<String>>` to keep your data structure consistent:

```java
    Map<String, LinkedList<String>> person = new HashMap<>();
    LinkedList<String> item   = new LinkedList<String>();
    LinkedList<String> item2  = new LinkedList<String>();

    item.add("Eggs");
    item.add("Bread");
    item.add("Ham");

    item2.add("Toilet roll");
    item2.add("Eggs");

    person.put("John", item);
    person.put("Amy", item2);
    person.put("Bob", new LinkedList<>());
    person.put("Michael", new LinkedList<>());

    System.out.println(person);
```

Up to you.